Flutter error while generating apk can help anyone for this I'm begginer
Execution failed for task ':google_mobile_ads:extractReleaseAnnotations'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_mobile_ads:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not download kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.3.0)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.3.0/kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar'.
> Tag mismatch!

I tried lots think but not resolved

Sometimes the cached files might be corrupted. Try clearing the Gradle cache
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
Update gradle-wrapper.properties and build.gradle files
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
In Android Studio, click on "File" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"
